# Why is it always the last message that appears when I input a different value input

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
org 100h

INCLUDE 'emu8086.inc'

jmp start1 ; start program
;========================
msg1    db " Program Converter umur" ,13,10,13,10,'$'
msg2    db " Nama :  $"   ; A string variable with a value
msg3    db " NIM : $"   ; A string variable with a value
msg4    db " input your age : $"     ; A string variable with a value
msg5    db " you are baby $"
msg6    db " you are kids $"
msg7    db " you are teen $"
msg8    db " you are adult $"
msg9    db " you are old $"

start1:
LEA DX,msg1         ;subfunction 9 output a string
MOV AH,9            ; DX points to <holds address of> the string
INT 21H
PUTC 13
PUTC 10             ; Output the message

start2:
LEA DX,msg2         ;subfunction 9 output a string
MOV AH,9            ; DX points to <holds address of> the string
INT 21H             ; Output the message         
CALL GET_STRING
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

start3:
LEA DX,msg3         ;subfunction 9 output a string
MOV AH,9            ; DX points to <holds address of> the string
INT 21H             ; Output the message     
CALL GET_STRING
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

start4:
LEA DX,msg4         ;subfunction 9 output a string
MOV AH,9            ; DX points to <holds address of> the string
INT 21H             ; Output the message         
CALL GET_STRING
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

CMP CX,5
JB baby   
JE baby 
CMP CX,10 
JB kids 
JE kids
CMP CX,20
JB teen
JE teen
CMP CX,50
JB adult
JE adult
JA old

baby :
LEA DX,msg5
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

kids :
LEA DX,msg6
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

teen :
LEA DX,msg7
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

adult :
LEA DX,msg8
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

old :
LEA DX,msg9
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
PUTC 13
PUTC 10

          
MOV AH,0
INT 16H

ret
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and only tag the programming language that you are actually using.

Comment: Did you try single stepping?  What did you see?  Can you tell us what's in `cx` when you `CMP CX,5`?

Comment: You are calling a procedure `GET_STRING` which is not defined in your program. I doubt that it magically returns the input string converted to a binary value in `CX`. Also notice that when it prints `you are a baby`, your program continues below  and prints `you are kids`, `you are teen` and so on.